# Render and populate a customized table

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new in R and would like to know how can I render a table using tags. In ui.R it appears ok inside a panel, but the request would be send and processed in server.R, wouldn't?

I'm trying like this **in ui.R**:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Painel 1"),

    fluidRow(
      column(12,
       wellPanel(
       renderUI("testecustom1")
      )
    )
   ) 
  )
```

**in server.R :**

```
server <- function(input,output){

  output$testecustom1 <- renderUI({
    tags$head(tags$table(border = 5, 
      tags$thead(
        tags$tr(
          tags$th(colspan = 7, height = 50, width = 200, 
          align = "center", "TABLE TITLE")
        )
      )
    ),
    tags$tbody(
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(align = "center",""),
        tags$td(colspan = 2,align = "center",strong("TOTAL")),
        tags$td(colspan = 2,align = "center",strong("MASCULINO")),
        tags$td(colspan = 2,align = "center",strong("FEMININO"))
      ),
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(align = "center",""),
        tags$td(align = "center",strong("%")),
        tags$td(align = "center",strong("IC 95%")),
        tags$td(align = "center",strong("%")),
        tags$td(align = "center",strong("IC 95%")),
        tags$td(align = "center",strong("%")),
        tags$td(align = "center",strong("IC 95%"))
      ),
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(align = "center", strong("BRASIL")),
        tags$td(align = "center",""),
        tags$td(align = "center",""),
        tags$td(align = "center", ""),
        tags$td(align = "center", ""),
        tags$td(align = "center", ""),
        tags$td(align = "center", "")
     ),
     tags$tr(
       tags$td(align = "center", strong("ALAGOAS")),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", "")
     ),
     tags$tr(
       tags$td(align = "center", strong("MACEIO")),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", ""),
       tags$td(align = "center", "")
      )
    ))  
  })
}
```

I'm still so confused with the functions. What would be the correct pair in both files to render and populate a customized table using tags?

It shows an empty panel. I'd like do fill in with my customized table.

Comment: When I see either multiple dots or 'etc' , I instantly know that the question will be lacking a [MCVE] and I leave the question. I suggest you learn to [edit] and fix this incomplete question.

Comment: Ok...the complete code now...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using tags, you will use them in the user interface (`ui`). Additionally, when you use `tags$head`, you're referring to the `head` of the entire HTML. You're going to put a table in the body of a webpage. Lastly, the elements that are *within* a table need to be *within* that element. You can add them to the element after the fact, but it's easier to nest it.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Painel 1"),
  tags$body(
    tags$table(border = 5, 
               tags$thead(
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$th(colspan = 7, height = 50, width = 200, 
                           align = "center", "TABLE TITLE")
                 )
               ),
               tags$tbody(
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td(align = "center",""),
                   tags$td(colspan = 2,align = "center",strong("TOTAL")),
                   tags$td(colspan = 2,align = "center",strong("MASCULINO")),
                   tags$td(colspan = 2,align = "center",strong("FEMININO"))
                 ),
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td(align = "center",""),
                   tags$td(align = "center",strong("%")),
                   tags$td(align = "center",strong("IC 95%")),
                   tags$td(align = "center",strong("%")),
                   tags$td(align = "center",strong("IC 95%")),
                   tags$td(align = "center",strong("%")),
                   tags$td(align = "center",strong("IC 95%"))
                 ),
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td(align = "center", strong("BRASIL")),
                   tags$td(align = "center",""),
                   tags$td(align = "center",""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", "")
                 ),
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td(align = "center", strong("ALAGOAS")),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", "")
                 ),
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td(align = "center", strong("MACEIO")),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", ""),
                   tags$td(align = "center", "")
                 )
               )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input,output){
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I see....and how can I populate the empty cells with dynamic data ? Can u show me and example ?

Comment: It depends on the data, how it changes, and where you want that data to go when it changes. The upward limit is close to an infinite number of possibilities. However, a straight `tag` built table will be cumbersome and clumsy. You really should use an R package that does a LOT of this work for you, for example, `DT`; you can read about that [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html).